# Would the trial of Jesus of Nazareth have been recorded on an Acta Diurna?

Tags: roman-empire, jesus

[Acta Diurna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acta_Diurna) were official notices in the Roman Republic and Roman Empire, which were displayed on message boards in other places. According to Wikipedia:

> Their original content included results of legal proceedings and outcomes of trials.

Would [the trial of Jesus of Nazareth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilate%27s_court) under Pontius Pilate have been recorded under an Acta Diurna? As a Roman official overseeing the trial and authorizing his crucifixion, this seems like a possibility. However, I'm not sure if the fact that Jesus wasn't a Roman citizen would mean that it wouldn't get recorded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very unlikely, as it did not take place at Rome.

The Acta Diurna was a daily record of court proceedings at Rome, for the information of the resident citizens of Rome.  Think of it as the record of the local court.  Provincial court proceedings would have been local affairs; if they had greater scope, the trial would have been referred to Rome, as happened with Paul of Tarsus.

Some historical analysis of the various [Acta is available here.](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Acta.html)  It includes citations to the ancient sources.  None of the actual *Acta* survive.

Comment: Paul's trial was referred to Rome not because it "had greater scope", but because Paul was a Roman citizen and himself insisted that he be tried in the capital. Or at least that is what it says in "Acts".

Comment: @fdb: Paul being a Roman citizen is just one example of such "greater scope".  Basically the local governor passed the case along to higher authority - always the safest route in an autocracy.